# Display audio waveform and zoom

Tags: java, audio

I'm able to display waveform but I don't know how to implement zoom in on the waveform.
Any idea?

Thanks piccolo

Answer (score 0):

By Zoom, I presume you mean horizontal zoom rather than vertical. The way audio editors do this is to scan the wavform breaking it up into time windows where each pixel in X represents some number of samples. It can be a fractional number, but you can get away with dis-allowing fractional zoom ratios without annoying the user too much. Once you zoom out a bit the max value is always a positive integer and the min value is always a negative integer.

for each pixel on the screen, you need to have to know the minimum sample value for that pixel and the maximum sample value. So you need a function that scans the waveform data in chunks and keeps track of the accumulated max and min for that chunk.

This is slow process, so professional audio editors keep a pre-calculated table of min and max values at some fixed zoom ratio. It might be at 512/1 or 1024/1. When you are drawing with a zoom ration of > 1024 samples/pixel, then you use the pre-calculated table. if you are below that ratio you get the data directly from the file. If you don't do this you will find that you drawing code gets to be too slow when you zoom out.

Its worthwhile to write code that handles all of the channels of the file in an single pass when doing this scanning, slowness here will make your whole program feel sluggish, it's the disk IO that matters here, the CPU has no trouble keeping up, so straightforward C++ code is fine for building the min/max tables, but you don't want to go through the file more than once and you want to do it sequentially.

Once you have the min/max tables, keep them around. You want to go back to the disk as little as possible and many of the reasons for wanting to repaint your window will not require you to rescan your min/max tables. The memory cost of holding on to them is not that high compared to the disk io cost of building them in the first place.

Then you draw the waveform by drawing a series of 1 pixel wide vertical lines between the max value and the min value for the time represented by that pixel. This should be quite fast if you are drawing from pre built min/max tables.

Answered by https://stackoverflow.com/users/234815/John%20Knoeller

Comment: Generally true, but just rendering the minimum and maximum will not be aethestically pleasing if the zoom ratio is large (zoomed out far).  If you zoom out far enough the waveform "shape" will be dominated by outlier samples and will start to look like random noise.  One approach that will look better is to compute the RMS power for all positive samples, and separately for all negative samples in each window.

Answer (score 0):

Working on this right now, c# with a little linq but should be easy enough to read and understand.  The idea here is to have a array of float values from -1 to 1 representing the amplitude for every sample in the wav file.  Then knowing how many samples per second, we then need a scaling factor - segments per second.  At this point you simply are reducing the datapoints and smoothing them out.   to zoom in really tight give a samples per second of 1000, to zoom way out maybe 5-10.     Note right now im just doing normal averaing, where this needs to be updated to be much more efficent and probably use RMS (root-mean-squared) averaging to make it perfect.

```
private List<float> BuildAverageSegments(float[] aryRawValues, int iSamplesPerSecond, int iSegmentsPerSecond)
            {
                double nDurationInSeconds = aryRawValues.Length/(double) iSamplesPerSecond;
                int iNumSegments = (int)Math.Round(iSegmentsPerSecond*nDurationInSeconds);
                int iSamplesPerSegment = (int) Math.Round(aryRawValues.Length/(double) iNumSegments); // total number of samples divided by the total number of segments
                List<float> colAvgSegVals = new List<float>();

                for(int i=0; i<iNumSegments-1; i++)
                {
                    int iStartIndex = i * iSamplesPerSegment;
                    int iEndIndex = (i + 1) * iSamplesPerSegment;
                    float fAverageSegVal = aryRawValues.Skip(iStartIndex).Take(iEndIndex - iStartIndex).Average();
                    colAvgSegVals.Add(fAverageSegVal);
                }

                return colAvgSegVals;
            }
```

Outside of this you need to get your audio into a wav format, you should be able to find source everywhere to read that data, then use something like this to convert the raw byte data to floats - again this is horribly rough and inefficent but clear

```
 public float[] GetFloatData()
        {
            //Scale Factor - SignificantBitsPerSample
            if (Data != null && Data.Length > 0)
            {
                float nMaxValue = (float) Math.Pow((double) 2, SignificantBitsPerSample);
                float[] aryFloats = new float[Data[0].Length];

                for (int i = 0; i < Data[0].Length; i++ )
                {
                    aryFloats[i] = Data[0][i]/nMaxValue;
                }
                return aryFloats;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```